# To make redirect to url with " and '

Tags: php, redirect

Hi I have link which has " and ' for example : `http://site.com/?sd=text&sery=&son="><ic=x onerror="`

```
<?
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://site.com/?sd=text&sery=&son="><ic=x onerror=");
exit;
?>
```

How correctly write script?

Comment: Have you looked into escape characters?
Edit: Nevermind, apparently those don't work. I'll keep this here, as it appears to be a common misconception.

Answer (score 6):

You must url encode it using php's [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function. This is the proper way to encode keys and values in querystrings. You must also escape quotes with a leading backslash in order for them to be included in double quoted string literals. Try this:

```
<?
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://site.com/?sd=text&sery=&son=" . urlencode("\"><ic=x onerror=\""));
exit;
?>
```

Alternatively, you may single quote your string literals in this case, which will eliminate the need to escape the double quotes. Note: If you do single quote your string then any  apostrophe characters appearing in your string would need to be escaped with a leading backslash. I don't see any in your example, despite the title and description of the question.

```
<?
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: http://site.com/?sd=text&sery=&son=' . urlencode('"><ic=x onerror="'));
exit;
?>
```